# Ubuntu 12.04 - Installing PHP with -fastcgi

Tags: 12.04, php

Does anyone know how to install PHP on Ubuntu with fastcgi enabled? I've installed my PHP from the following site: http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-setup-latest-version-of-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

I've looked into installing fastcgi via (apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi) and have come up with the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-fastcgi : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've hit the wall on this without any solutions, am running the latest Apache version 2.4, could use some help on this.

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes gave it a look and didn't see a solution for resolving a dependency that is an older version that what I have installed currently.

Comment: The developer who has ppa:ondrej/php5 which you have installed apache from, has another ppa:ondrej/apache2 which has built libapache2-mod-fastcgi But I'm not sure it will work or conflict with other apache as both have apache2.4. See https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2?field.series_filter=precise

Comment: Thanks for providing this link, am hesitant to try it after what happened last time! Working on a project and don't want uninstall apache2 just yet.

Comment: A good way to test in such productive environment, is to use Virtual Machine to test before deployment. You can remove old comments to clean up this post, as someone may come and give better solution. He don't have to read such pile.

Comment: Fixed, installed the fastcgi mod and reinstalled apache2, it works now. Put up an answer, thanks for the help Sneetsher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer who has `ppa:ondrej/php5` which you have installed Apache2 from, has another `ppa:ondrej/apache2` which has built `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` for  `apache2.4`.

See https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2?field.series_filter=precise

Both PPA's has `apache2.4`, You may download only `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` package to avoid Apache2 version racing if they are not the same.

But as of 2016 Feb, libapache2-mod-fastcgi in the ppa:ondrej/apache2 only supports trusty 14.04, vivid, 15.04, and wily 15.10. Seems there is no support for precise 12.04.